# Store a jQuery object immutably locally for later

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a DIV with nested elements on page-load using Pug. Later, the user filters those elements but I need to `.remove()` them rather than using `.hide()`.

(I need to do this, at least in the current version of my code.)

I'm trying to stash the container DIV away for later, so when I perform my 'clear those filters' action I can just restore the whole thing using `.clone()`, therefore getting back the elements I `.remove()`'d.

This is all happening client-side, so I'm putting it on `window`. The strange thing is, my filter action is affecting the object I've stashed! I've tried `.freeze()`, making a new object, whatever – it just keeps being affected. Rows that I filter from the visible DIV are being removed from what I thought was an immutable copy.

I need to do all of this with jQuery, using `true` for deep cloning. The child DIVs have event listeners attached to them which I want to restore.

So, two questions:

1. Is there somewhere more sensible I should be stashing this object?
2. How is it being modified in the first place?! Nowhere in my code do I touch it after creation. I get the whole "it's a pointer not a copy" thing, but by creating a new object using `Object.freeze(originalObject)` I thought I was getting around that?

Deeply confused. :-/ I'm reasonably new to JS/jQuery so forgive me if I'm just being a fool.

Comment: I think you'd get some better suggestions if you provided some code. Particularly around how you're filtering your array and then displaying the filtered results.  Ultimately, if you're driving this from that data ("model") then it should be relatively easy to "restore" your stashed version.

Comment: Curious why you're `.remove()`ing something you want to be able to restore? Maybe some example code to better understand what you're doing?

Comment: My code was way too complicated to try to extract bits - which was probably my issue in the first place. I've refactored and am now using CSS classes to hide rows, like I should have all along. What's protocol, should I delete this pointless question?